# Given moments find extrema of expectation of a function

Tags: optimization, random-variables

Consider random variables $Y$ with finite support: $\mathbb{P}(\vert Y\vert \le c) = 1$ and given moments: $\mathbb{E}Y = 0, \text{Var}Y = \sigma^2$. How to find such Y that maximizes functional $\mathbb{E}e^Y$?

I suppose we can not use variational calculus for this problem. I found the known fact that maximum is reached on discrete random variable with at most $K+1$ values, where $K$ is the number of given moments. But I can not prove this fact.

May be it can be solved without this fact? Any hint is welcome.

Comment: This question has been asked in almost identical language by a different user(name) on [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/183996/6633) and completely and correctly answered by the OP too. About the only difference in the questions is the use of $a$ in place of the $c$ here. A homework or take-home exam question maybe?